# Prevent all instantiations of a template class - including supported types

Tags: c++, templates, extern, explicit-instantiation

If I have a template class `MyClass<T>` and if I explicitly instantiate for `int` and `float` (in a `cpp` file) then I can use `extern template class MyClass<int>` and `extern template class MyClass<float>` to prevent any compilation unit encountering this class from instantiating it for `int` and `float` unnecessarily. Of course, for any other type, the class will still get instantiated.

Now I have a class `MyClass2<T>` which only works with `int`, `float`, `char`, `double`, `short` and their unsigned variants where applicable. Since I know all the types beforehand, the definitions of all the methods in this class are in the `cpp` file. This is also where I explicitly instantiate `MyClass2<T>` for all the above mentioned types. In the header, I have `static_assert` preventing the user from creating `MyClass2<T>` with an unsupported type.

Is there any way to completely prevent `MyClass2<T>` from instantiating (e.g. `extern template class MyClass2;` although I know that doesn't work) for all types *including supported types*? Like a *catch all* for `extern template`? I want to avoid typing out `extern template class MyClass2<int>` for all the supported types.

Considering I have already explicitly instantiated the class for those types, it seems not only redundant but for big projects (like the one I am working on) yet another few lines that I need to maintain each time a new type is added.

Comment: Our code is cross platform so `MSVC++ 2010-2013`, `CLang in XCode 6`, and `GCC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This honestly sounds like the job for a macro:

```
// explicit_instantiations.h
#ifndef PERFORM_INSTANTIANTION
#define EXTERNALLY_INSTANTIATED extern
#else
#define EXTERNALLY_INSTANTIATED
#endif

EXTERNALLY_INSTANTIATED template class MyClass<int>;
EXTERNALLY_INSTANTIATED template class MyClass<float>;
// etc.

// header
#include "explicit_instantiations.h"

// cpp file
#define PERFORM_INSTANTIATION
#include "explicit_instantiations.h"
```

Comment: That is not a bad idea at all. I will have extra files but maintainability will make up for it. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SFINAE something like following

```
template<typename T>
using value_type =  typename std::enable_if<
                    std::is_same<float, T>::value ||
                    std::is_same<double, T>::value
                    //...other supported types goes here
                   >::type  ;



template<class T, class Enable = void>
class  MyClass2 ;

template<class T>
class MyClass2<T, value_type<T> > 
{
};

 MyClass2<float> t;
 MyClass2<int> t1; // Error !
```

<sup>See [*`Here`*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/636f68a09e34c148)</sup>

Comment: @Barry Why only `value_type<T>` ?

Comment: So two-fold. I think either drop the `typename` in front of the `enable_if` (which as-is you don't need), or add the `::type` at the end of it so you can drop it in `MyClass2`. Personally, I like using template aliases mainly to avoid having the `typename X::type` cruft everywhere...

Comment: I am already using `static_assert` to avoid instantiating unsupported types. That is not an issue. The issue is that all the supported types are being compiled multiple times by all compilation units ballooning compile times. I would like to know if there is a catch all for `extern template class` to avoid instantiating all types, _including_ unsupported types because these are being instantiated in their respective `cpp` files.

Comment: @T.C. I think he meant `SFINAE`, _substitution failure is not an error_.

Comment: @Samaursa I still don't get the problem 'catch all' for `extern template class` ?

Comment: (just in case you are unclear on its usage) `extern template class` is used to prevent the compiler from instantiating `MyClass2<int>` where ever it encounters it (which the linker ignores). Problem is that there is no _catch all_ for this keyword as far as I know which allows me to type `extern template class MyClass2` so that any type that is used with `MyClass2;` (instead of `extern template class MyClass2<int>;` for every type I support) prevents the compiler from instantiating the class. This is because I have instantiations for all supported types in the `cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base {};

template <typename T> 
struct Supported;

template <> 
struct Supported<int> : public Base<int>
{};
```

Comment: That solves one issue but opens a few more. Now I have a header full of these classes (which is okay) and I'll have to redefine all the constructors. The biggest issue is that I will have to change the header each time a new type is supported internally (and explicitly instantiated). And for each new type I'll have to do that, which is, again, more maintenance. I'd rather type `extern template class` in this case :)

Comment: You need the change in the header to get all compile time information. Otherwise, the type is a run time type (boost::any), you avoid, likely.